# How to pass string value as request body to the post method of third party API

Tags: go, http-post

I am trying for call external API call using POST method,

So for above POST API call i am facing an issue for content body not able to pass file path weblink as parameter.

```
   postBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{      
    "www://xyz.org/file.txt",                    

   })

   requestBody := bytes.NewBuffer(postBody)

`  resp, err := http.Post(("--POST API call--", "application/json", requestBody )
`
```

So if requestBody will fetch POST API call then, it should be allow to pass as a parameter with content body.

but its creating issue as below I have attached Postman snap where we can get to know content body is passing as null which should be like value of `"www://xyz.org/file.txt"`

normally POST call having requestBody body like below

```
 postBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
      "Key1":  "Value1",
      "key2": "Value2",
   })
```

**But in my case as below **
whichever file path I am calling that pass as a default web url value without key

```
 postBody, _ := json.Marshal(map[string]string{
       "www://xyz.org/file.txt",--------> // here no key available, only value as a string value
   })
```

Comment: You cannot have a map value without a key. By definition.

Comment: What exactly are you trying to accomplish?

Comment: actually which external API i used to call using POST method that only required file path as parameter and file is providing from web URL and its content type is "application/json"

Comment: your goal is to upload a binary file to your HTTP request? or what else?

Comment: I have resolved this issue using below logic and its work without key pair value default string value can able to pass as content body "application/json"                                                                                
----------------------------------------------------------------------------------------------
requestBody, _ := json.Marshal(string("https://example.org/filepath.txt"))
response, err := http.Post("https://samplepostAPI.org", "application/json", bytes.NewBuffer(requestBody))